# Ошибка валидации в python высвечивается как обычный текст, а хотелось бы, чтоб как ошибка

Tags: python, django

Есть пользовательская валидация:

```
def clean_title(self):
    title = self.cleaned_data['title']
    if title[0] == title[0].lower():
        raise ValidationError("Название должно начинаться с заглавной буквы")
    return title
```

На сайте высвечивается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это код в шаблоне

```
{% block content %}
<h2>Добавление книги:</h2>
<form action="{% url 'add_book' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for f in form %}
        <p><label class="form-label" for="{{f.id_for_label}}">{{f.label}}: </label>{{ f }}</p>
        <div class="form-errors"> {{ f.errors }} </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Это вьюшка

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddBooks(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = AddBooks()
    return render(request, 'book_app/add_page.html', context={'form': form})
```

Хотелось бы, чтоб ошибка высвечивалась красным и без точки

Comment: css напиши на этот элемент

Comment: Дело только в css? Просто я по видеоурокам учусь, css код оттуда взял, а на видео ошибка высвечивается так как надо

Comment: похоже css не прикрепился к документу. да дело только в css